# Default text for DropDownList

Tags: winforms, powershell, combobox

For a long time I used the usual `DropDown` as a `ComboBoxStyle`. However, I have only 2 items in the `ComboBox` and searching manually in this case looks unreasonable. Therefore, I decided to refer to `DropDownList`, since the text in it is immutable.

However, along with this I ran into a problem. In the case when no element is selected (if I understand correctly, in this case the -1 element is selected) I can not display the default text, for example, an invitation to select an element from the list. The variant with `ComboBox.Text ("Please, select any value")` no longer works (because the text is immutable) and here I am stumped, because I do not know what to do.

Sure, I have tried to look for something in the C# branch, but did not find anything working for powershell. Here is the option I have tried and which does not works:

```
$MethodComboBox.Add_TextChanged($defaultLabel)
$defaultLabel =
{
    if ($ComboBox.SelectedIndex -lt 0)
    {
        $ComboBox.Text = "Please, select any value";
    }
    else
    {
        $ComboBox.Text = $ComboBox.SelectedText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `DrawMode` of the `ComboBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and then handle `DrawItem` event and render a custom select text when index is `-1`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$combo = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combo.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList
$combo.DrawMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode]::OwnerDrawFixed
$combo.Width = 200
$combo.ItemHeight = 24
$combo.Items.Add("Male")
$combo.Items.Add("Female")
$form.Controls.Add($combo)
$combo.Add_DrawItem({param($sender,$e)
    $text = "-- Select Gender --"
    if ($e.Index -gt -1){
        $text = $sender.GetItemText($sender.Items[$e.Index])
    }
    $e.DrawBackground()
    [System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::DrawText($e.Graphics, $text, $combo.Font, `
        $e.Bounds, $e.ForeColor, [System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags]::Default)
})
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

[image]
[image]